# Process 'command 'C:/Java/jdk8/bin/java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, restart

Today when I use Spring Boot to restart my application then the console prompted that

```
Execution failed for task ':Application.main()'.
> Process 'command 'C:/Java/jdk8/bin/java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I don't know how to resolve this issue

This is my `application.java` and `application.yaml`

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
   }
}

server:
  port: 80
```

and the version of Spring Boot and Gradle is 2.3.7.RELEASE and 6.1.1

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it because some ports are occupied?

Answer (score -1):

Okay,I have resloved the issue and I will share you.

In the gradle cache file, I found some logs like below

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

 Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded 
 datasource could be configured.

 Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


 Action:

 Consider the following:
   If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

this issue is I dont have some database config for SpringBoot start.
so when I added database config in the resource folder and created an application.yaml file,then start successful.

That's all,Maybe next time we can add the config file first or we can config log for ourself.